# How long did it take for US 7755660 patent to get issued?

Tags: us7755660

In reference to the patent: [US7755660](https://www.google.com/patents/US7755660)

How long did it take overall to get issued?

Answer (score 0):

It took them 7 years 2 months and 10 days from priority date for grant. patent prosecution involved one Request for examination.